# Fetching data with React Hooks - Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, axios, react-hooks

Trying to fetch data from the NHL API, using React Hooks.

Link to [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-brook-flxdf?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).

When I comment out the  tag and it's content in the return statement, my console log does fetch the API successfully. However, I'm getting an error in the console when the  tag's content (the .map statement), saying "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined".

Trying to figure out why this error is displaying, and why I can't map the data defined from the API.

App.JS

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import axios from "axios";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({ people: [] });
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios(
        "https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/8475166?expand=person.stats&stats=yearByYear,careerRegularSeason&expand=stats.team&site=en_nhlCA"
      );
      setData(result.data.people);
      console.log(result.data.people);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <ul>
      {data.people.map(item => (
        <li key={item.objectID}>
          <p>{item.id}</p>
          <p>{item.primaryNumber}</p>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

export default App;

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess it should be

```
setData({ people: result.data.people });
```

You're setting the data in an object property called people in your state variable.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `setData(result.data.people)` !

The initial state which you provide is quite different from the way you set data.

Initial state: `data = {people: []}`
(So now you can map like : data.people)

In use effect: `data = result.data.people`

So the solution is either you change the initial state and then change how to loop.

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);  // Line #8

setData(result.data.people);  // Line # 14
                              // Line # 22
{data.map(item => (    
 <li key={item.objectID}>
   <p>{item.id}</p>
   <p>{item.primaryNumber}</p>
 </li>
))}
```

or you can change the way you assign after fetching the result.

```
setData({people: result.data.people})
```

I would have personally favored the first solution as I do not see any reason to have data being Object. Or I could have simply called it "people"